# slide menu from background to left

Tags: jquery

```
    -------------
    | header    |
    ------------ 
    |  |        | 
    | L|content | 
    |  |        | 
    -------------

    -------------
    | header    |
 ---------------- 
|  <- |         | 
| L   |content  | 
|  <- |         | 
-----------------
```

I need to create a JQuery box of 250px width and 300 height. It will comprise of (1) header (2) a small bar on left which should toggle slide left ward (to display menu) and back at original position on  click and (3) a right section of content. I'm fairly new in JQuery and could think of following code which works more or less in chrome but fails dramatically in IE.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery[1].js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #gcontainer {
            height:300px;
            width:350px;
            background-color:#ffffff;
            margin-left:100px;

        }

        #gheader{
            height:50px;
            width:350px;
            background-color:#feee00;

        }

        #gtray{
            height:250px;
            background-color:#006600;
            width:130px;
            float:left;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-right:0px;
            position:relative;
            z-index:0;
            overflow:hidden:
        }

        #gcontainer{
            height:250px;
            width:320px;
            margin-left:30px;
            background-color:darkblue;
            float:left;
            position:absolute;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(function(){
        $('#gtray').toggle(
        function()
            {
                $(this).stop(true).animate({marginLeft:'-100px'},'slow');
            }, 
        function()
            {
                $(this).stop(true).animate({marginLeft:'0px'},'slow');
            });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="gcontainer">
    <div id="gheader"><h2>HEADER</h2></div>
    <div id="gtray">
        <span id="expander" style="width:30px;height:250px;float:left;background-color:red">O<br>p<br>e<br>n</span>
        <span style="float:left">asdas<br>SDasd<br>asdasdasd<br>asdasd<br>Sdasd</span>
    </div>
    <div id="gcontainer"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here seems to be with your HTML/CSS, not javascript/jquery. First, you should not have multiple divs with the same ID. So I am not sure why you have`#gcontainer` twice. If you want to apply the same style to multiple divs use classes. In your css, you are styling `#gcontainer` twice, which also does not make sense as the second time overwrites the first one. Also remember to always add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your pages or browsers will render in quirks mode, which can do all sorts of unexpected things.

Anyways, I removed the extra #gcontainer in your HTML and CSS and edited some of the margins. Finally, I added a wrapper around the whole thing and put margin on the left, so your slide out would not go off the screen. This should work in IE and Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper {
        margin-left: 100px;
        }

        #gheader{
            height:50px;
            width:350px;
            background-color:#feee00;

        }

        #gtray{
            height:250px;
            background-color:#006600;
            width:130px;
            float:left;
            margin-left:0px;
            margin-right:-130px;
            position:relative;
            z-index:0;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        #gcontainer{
            height:250px;
            width:320px;
            margin-left:30px;
            background-color:darkblue;
            float:left;
            position:absolute;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(function(){
        $('#gtray').toggle(
        function()
            {
                $(this).stop(true).animate({marginLeft:'-100px'},'slow');
            }, 
        function()
            {
                $(this).stop(true).animate({marginLeft:'0px'},'slow');
            });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="gheader"><h2>HEADER</h2></div>
    <div id="gtray">
        <span id="expander" style="width:30px;height:250px;float:left;background-color:red">O<br>p<br>e<br>n</span>
        <span style="float:left">asdas<br>SDasd<br>asdasdasd<br>asdasd<br>Sdasd</span>
    </div>
    <div id="gcontainer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Sanketh... Thanks. It is working great in both IE & chrome. However, there is one minor glitch still there... When the slider tray is scrolling to left, you would see that slide bar changes its width for a moment which causes "Open" to cut off for a sec. How can this issue be resolved as it doesn't result in a neat & tidy animation. thanks.

Comment: If you slow down the slide (change the 'slow' to a number in ms), it will maybe look a bit smoother. If you are just worried about text getting cut off, you could always just add some padding around the Open. Other than that, you may want to look into using another tool like the [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) or [jQuery UI's Effect](http://jqueryui.com/docs/effect/) which may offer some more options for smoothness. Hopefully those help